# A totally rookery in TypeScript with Function Overloading

Tags: function, typescript, undefined, overloading

I'm just learning TypeScript from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_functions.htm) , at the Function Overloads section, got an 'undefined' error, Like I said I'm very new on TypeScript, don't know what is going on and how to fix it, please help!

Here is the snippet:

```
function foo_overload(s: string): void;
function foo_overload(n: number, s: string): void;
function foo_overload(x: any, y?: any): void {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
}

foo_overload("Jack")
foo_overload(50, "Zhao");
```

And when I compile and execute this, the output like this:

```
Jack
undefined
50
Zhao
```

What the "**undefined**" it is?

Comment: It's `y`, when you don't pass any value for that optional parameter. What precisely does *"a totally rookery"* mean?

Comment: `undefined` isn't an error; it's a value.

Comment: @Ryan, I'm sorry, you are right, I mean why I can get this 'undefined'.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it means that I'm a very beginner with TypeScript.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you are right too, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern matching works well until you hit `function foo_overload(x: any, y?: any):`.

In that function, while you declare `y` to be optional, you invoke `y` with `console.log(y)`, so it returns undefined, as in the first function invocation, you did not offer a `y` value (there is nothing after Jack).

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are right, I'm outputting y but nothing was given, that's why 'undefined' shows.